# How to receive GPRS data and view it on a webpage?

Tags: html, gprs

How to receive GPRS data and view it on a webpage?

I am doing a GPRS Datalogger. It sends Data of some sensors to a web server using GPRS. I want to be able to view this data on a webpage in a browser say Google Chrome. Also I need the data which is received by server to be stored in a database. How should I proceed with the designing of Front end for my application? Should I use HTML 5, PHP and MySQL? Is there an example code which receives data from GPRS and shows it on a webpage?

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to help you if you show us how you send the data to the webserver. Since you say you are sending it, you should already "know" how the server receives it. ;

To show it you can of course use HTML, PHP and MySQL, but any other databases or frameworks will also do - this is really a matter of taste.